# How to create a build and launch command in VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

Im using VSCodium. I would like to combine my Build and Launch commands into one command.
My `launch.json` looks like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Debug",
            "type": "gdb",
            "request": "launch",
            "target": "./bin/minetest",
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "valuesFormatting": "parseText"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what my build command is. To build I open the command palette and select CMake: Build and it builds.
If I get errors in the build then Id prefer the launch command to fail.
I know I need to edit my `tasks.json` but am not sure on the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use CMake Tools' interface for running targets (Ex. from the CMake View, or from the command palette- `CMake: Debug` / `CMake: Run Without Debugging`), then whatever you have set in [the `cmake.buildBeforeRun` setting](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/main/docs/cmake-settings.md#cmake-settings) (which defaults to `true`) should take effect.

If you're not using the mechanisms provided by the CMake Tools extension for running things, and instead are using a non-CMake launch config, then typically people put their build command in a [task](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) and specify the task in the `preLaunchTask` property of the corresponding launch config(s).